# Writing into RAM Areas I am not addressing

Tags: c, pointers

I currently have a problem with my C code concerning RAM writes that appear to happen (I checked by watching a member of a structure via gdb) even though I did not actively intend to write to that area.

My structs are declared as followed:

```
typedef struct tcb {
    unsigned int tid;
    thread_state_t state;
    pthread_t thread;
    sem_t sema;
    unsigned long interval;
    unsigned long rtime;
} tcb_t ;

typedef struct node {
    tcb_t *tcb;
} node;

typedef struct entry entry; 

typedef struct entry {
    entry *next;
    entry *prev;
    node node;
} entry;
```

These definitions are provided and I can not change them.
I now initialize an array of `entry` with this code:

```
entry = malloc((num_threads) * sizeof(entry));

for (i = 0; i < num_threads; i++)
{
    entry[i].next = NULL;
    entry[i].prev = NULL;
    entry[i].node.tcb = malloc(sizeof(tcb_t));
    entry[i].node.tcb->tid = i;
    entry[i].node.tcb->state = THREAD_RUNNABLE; //initialize value to show the scheduler this thread works for the first time
    entry[i].node.tcb->interval = interval;

}
```

The other fields are not meant to initialized at this point. However once I run my code with let's say `num_threads = 6`, the value for `entry[0].node.tcb->tid` lost its value 0 but holds something strange (looks like a pointer to me).

When setting a watchpoint in gdb for this field it notifies me at the line `entry[i].node.tcb = malloc(sizeof(tcb_t));` that my value was overwritten (at this point `i` holds the value 2). Why is this?

Comment: gdb watchpoint notifies you at the line `entry[i].node.tcb = malloc(sizeof(tcb_t));` with _what value of_ `i`?

Comment: `valgrind` may help you

Comment: The value of i i get notified at is i = 2, i post the gdb output below (might look messy, sorry for that)


255                     entry[i].node.tcb = malloc(sizeof(tcb_t));
(gdb) n
Hardware watchpoint 2: entry[0].node.tcb->tid

Old value = 0
New value = 6299888
main (argc=3, argv=0x7fffffffe688) at aufgabe_5.c:256
256                     entry[i].node.tcb->tid = i;
(gdb) print i
$1 = 2

Comment: Are you certain that your version of `malloc` is thread safe?  If you are running multiple threads with an unsafe `malloc`, it could cause issues like this.  Another thought is that you are watching unallocated memory in GDB, then it warns you that the value changes upon malloc because it indeed did change.  It depends on where you placed your watch.  Last, is there any chance to run this only as a single thread to see if the problem goes away?

Comment: @Orel How would another debuger help me?

Comment: @PfannkuchenXD, place that information back in the original question instead of putting it in comments - it will be much easier for everyone to read that way.

Comment: I already removed all other threads of my code to check if the problem can be traced back to not-threadsafe memory allocation.
Furthermore i include <stdlib.h> and <stdio.h>, which should include threadsafe malloc-functions, shouldn't they?
I placed my watchpoint by the command `watch entry[0].node.tcb->tid`, which should be right. As the loop suggests the memory area actually is allocated...

Comment: valgrind can give you quick info about memory error...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot have the line

```
entry = malloc((num_threads) * sizeof(entry));
```

as written - it does not compile. Since your program has lines such as

```
entry[i].next = NULL;
```

I guess it is actually

```
entry *entry = malloc((num_threads) * sizeof(entry));
```

So now what is `sizeof(entry)`? My little test program tells me it is `4`, the size of the pointer, not the struct.

So please use unique identifiers.

Comment: Well, the canonical `sizeof` here would be `sizeof(*entry)` (dererencing the variable, which gets nice DRY behavior by having the type of the variable only reference in the declaration, not the allocation too), which should get the correct size. That said, yeah, reusing the type name as the variable name is a bad idea.

Comment: Thank you. I am doing this in terms of homework and we always recieve a "frame" of code that they want us to fill. This code"frame" included the line `entry *entry`. It works now, that i changed the variables name.

Comment: The above comment is a good one: had you used `sizeof *entry` the duplicated name would not have mattered. This error (getting the size of pointer) is an old chestnut. Aside: `sizeof` only needs parentheses when referring to a *type*, but not when referring to a variable.